# How do I copy data from two computers connected with cross-over cable?

Tags: gnome, networking, 10.04

A tech friend installed Ubuntu 10.04 on an older Dell desktop (Pentium 4); it has an odd memory/unmatched tabs pair but he installed something that compensates for that. I can use the KDE lightweight desktop but if I try to use gnome (more features) my mouse quits working. He told me not to upgrade to any higher versions since I'm a Linux newbie and 10.04 makes more sense for learning.

I have 12.04 LTS installed on another system and am more or less clueless how to identify & install packages with missing dependencies.

Anyway I have data on the 12.04 system that I want to move to the 10.04 (back-up) system, have cross-over cable installed but need to know how to create permissions on both systems so they can "see" what's on the other. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please try to ask only one question per issue, this site works best then. In case your mouse issue cant be resolved you may ask again but do add as much details as possible.

Answer (score 0):

10.04 hits end of life on the may 9th 2013
i do not suggest upgrading to a newer ubuntu on a Pentium 4 with integrated graphics (you will have a bad time)
I would suggest 32bit xubuntu or lubuntu as a clean install for a system that old

As for using a crossover cable (if you have no networking knowledge use a flash drive/cd/dvd)
What I would do is install openssh-server (look in the software center) on one of the systems
then you will need to set the IP Address to static ones on both systems (or connect via router)
eg: 172.0.0.1 and 172.0.0.2, I assume you have some networking knowledge to intend to use a crossover cable
and on the system that you did not install openssh-server on run

```
scp -r user@172.0.0.2:~/Pictures ~/
```

That will copy everything in your Pictures folder from the other system to the one you run the command on
I assumed you made the address on the system with openssh-server on it 172.0.0.2
If you are using a router run `ifconfig` to get your address
eth=hardware and wlan=wireless you want the "inet addr"

As for the mouse thing, i don't have enough info to say anything useful about that.
for example is it a trackpad mouse or a usb or PS/2 Mouse and the output of lsusb

Comment: Dear GM-script-Writer: Thank you for the reply. Truthfully what you said is much like foreign language, I will review it with my tech buddy. So Pentium 4 is old? Wow I am barely keeping up with the best computers I've owned. Maybe more memory will fix the mouse. Thanks again.

Comment: yes the "Pentium 4" is ancient, you may be mixing the name up though. What does this command give you `sudo hwinfo --cpu 2>/dev/null|grep Model | tail -1` It may be necessary to install hwinfo (`sudo apt-get install -y hwinfo`)